# Execute Python in cloud

Tags: python

My web server does not allow me to install additional Python modules. Is there a way to execute a Python script on a cloud server somewhere else (which does allow addons). So the server 1 handles web requests and calls Python on server 2 which returns output back to server 1.

Comment: have you tried `virtualenv`? you can install anything you like into a virtualenv...

Comment: Will virtualenv be installed, or I have to install it?

Comment: I don't know. try typing `which virtualenv` on the shell and see what it says.

Comment: virtualenv is kinda of an additional module, if you can install it, it means that you can install other modules. If it's preinstalled, then you have your solution!

Comment: are you running on google app engine?

Comment: Added a `virtualenv` answer; FYI if your host does not provide `virtualenv` then it's time to move hosts if you intend of using python with any sort of regularity.

Answer (score 2):

It's probably easier to just extract the contents of the python modules to some relative folder and import them that way. Of course, you potentially lose a whole bunch of good properties of modules/package management, but at least you get your stuff working..

Note that this approach is great for simply getting it quickly working at the start. Afterwards, you will probably want to get a more robust/decoupled solution by using a proper package management utility like the one described in ldrumm's answer.

Comment: Like the idea, but not all python modules are easy to integrate this way. Some needs extra system dependencies, others are not open source...

Comment: Yes, but if it works well for the modules in this particular case, then it is a possible solution.

Comment: And that is why I upvoted it :p

Comment: -1.  This is not a solution.  Have you ever tried maintaining a solution like that?  What happens when you need to update a package?

Comment: Actually, it is a solution. Yes, I have tried to maintain a solution like that. Have you considered that Dirk might have an under-privileged account and may not have access to virtualenv, in which case, suggesting it as a solution creates a chicken-egg problem. If you are updating third party libraries/dependencies that often, you are doing it wrong anyway. Considering it will mostly be in a separate part of the source tree, and you might not even have to change anything to make it work; Your downvote is an angry overreaction. I love the answers here simply ignoring the main constraint.

Answer (score 1):

`virtualenv` is the package you want, and is indispensible for any Python developer.

It solves at least two problems:

**Installing packages without privileges**

`virtualenv` allows you to create your own local installation of any package within a given directory, which means that you can install packages without root privileges.

```
mkdir myvirtualenv && cd myvirtualenv && virtualenv --no-site-packages . && source bin/activate
```

That command creates a new directory, and then creates a new virtualenv.  This contains bin  `include`  `lib`  `local` so you have a standard directory set up for you new files.

The line `source bin/activate` changes your `$PATH` setting so that instead of referencing system-packages, it looks in the local directories first.

**Installing specific versions of packages**

Many projects require specific versions of packages.  This might conflict with the requirements of another project on the system. `virtualenv` to the rescue:

`source bin/activate && pip install foo==1.2.3`

`virtualenv` almost always goes hand-in-hand with `pip` which allows you install any version of a package into the active `virtualenv`.  Multiple projects can then coexist with different version/package requirements.

[The package can be found here](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/virtualenv)

**edit**

Once you have downloaded the package from the linked page, and extracted its contents (with `tar -xzf virtualenv-1.10.1.tar.gz`), you can just run `python virtualenv.py` from the root directory of the extracted package.

Comment: And, uh, how does he install this package...

Comment: @PreetKukreti revenge?

Comment: hardly. Its logically sound. Suggesting that he moves host or creates a VPS or gets root account is akin to responding "get better hardware" to an optimization question.

Comment: @PreetKukreti True, but as I don't know what packages the OP has installed I was providing a potential long-term solution, rather than an ugly hack that will cause a great deal of frustration with the package-dependencies.  It is clear that any long-term interest in Python development will hinge on having `virtualenv` installed.  He can install the package and run `python virtualenv.py` from the linked pypi page.  You raise a good point; I neglected this part.  I'll edit my answer as appropriate.

Comment: "embedding" third party libs/headers/modules etc as part of the source tree of actual project is not uncommon in the real world, since a lot of code depends on a library's API and over time, even the bugs of a particular release. In large-scale projects, since the project code and third party libs are so closely tied together, and affected by breaking changes in updates, that in many cases it actually *makes sense* and is *desirable* to "bake in" certain libraries as part of the source tree. In these cases, it is far from an ugly hack. The only difference is where you unpack the module.

Comment: @PreetKukreti Yes. That is what virtualenv is for

Comment: Except, my solution works where you dont have privileges to install modules, which is the primary point of the entire question. Many of the projects that do this do not, in fact use virtualenv.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/38983/discussion-between-ldrumm-and-preet-kukreti)

Answer (score 0):

That's a twisted way of doing a simple python web server. 
The easiest way would be to create a VPS, any cloud provider can do it. 
(Create a small instance on amazon for example).

From there, you will have a full Linux distribution and you can install any version of python you want using any modules, plugins and scripts you want.

But once you've managed to do so, why not just move your webserver to the cloud removing the overhead of having to call a secondary server.

Answer (score 0):

I would personally try to become as independent on the system python as possible so as to be able to do do anything I want with/for my Python apps. The thing that allows you to achieve that anywhere without root access is Pythonz: https://github.com/saghul/pythonz

(Also there is https://github.com/yyuu/pyenv)

You can then use `virtualenv` on top of that, which is also recommended by the author of Pythonz.

You can also then just install your non-Python dependencies either directly into the Pythonz-managed Python prefix, or into the `virtualenv` prefix.